# How to install headless Ubuntu with option for GUI + wireless

Tags: wireless, headless

I have a wireless PC that I normally will run headless (using the monitor and keyboard/mouse for other PCs).  And access via SSH to manage NFS and samba.

I had the PC running in headless only, and later needed and then installed the window manager for what should have been temporary use. On reboot, it now starts up into the window manager, but the wireless is broken.

I plan to start from scratch on the install now.  My configuration is maybe a bit unusual, and I'm not finding a lot of guidance on how to do this.

I want to install Ubuntu or one of its flavors to run as headless, but where I can then start the GUI from the command line (startx or similar).  And here's one trick for this...wireless works in both cases.

Any advice is appreciated!

Comment: How about your wireless setup configuration for the headless mode?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/search?tab=votes&q=headless+wifi + https://askubuntu.com/search?q=disable+x+at+boot

Comment: Of what do you want to start the GUI?

Comment: Ubuntu installers are designed to use a monitor/keyboard for the easiest install experience for most users. (There are exceptions for VMs and Containers). While it's possible to install other ways, it's not easy and not recommended for beginners. Are you saying that you *cannot* use a monitor/keyboard for the install? You might easily spend several days experimenting to save the few minutes of attaching a keyboard/monitor. See https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/please-test-autoinstalls-for-20-04/15250/305 for examples of the pain points.

Comment: Sorry, to be clear, I can install with KVM.  I just want to be able to remove KVM after and have the PC boot into headless text/console mode.  And then have the option to add KVM later and start the window manager for temporary use where I need a GUI.  Then remove KVM and go back to text/console mode.   My recent experience is that the wireless settings were not able to make the transition. Once I installed the window manager, its wireless utility broke the settings for text/console mode.  I  also tried in the past running the window manager full time, just removing KVM as needed. Didn't work.

Comment: `sudo systemctl set-default multi-user.target` boots to text/console by default. `sudo systemctl set-default graphical.target` boots to desktop manager and graphical environment by default after boot. Not sure if you can switch between those modes on a running system.